# set if to multiple variables

Tags: php, mysql, user-interface

I want to try something like this (below is not a code, I had to show it as an code because otherwise it wouldn't allow me to post it.)

```
If Variable1 = 1  then AllVariables should update in mysql as 1.
If Variable2 = 1 then AllVariables should update in mysql as 1.
If Variable1 and Variable 2 = 1, then AllVariables should update in mysql as 2
```

Tried to do

```
if($Variable1 == 1) {
$sql = "UPDATE users set AllVariables = 1 WHERE id = $username"; }
```

Is this possible? if so, is there any shorter and better way than I'm doing it? because i tried 1000 rewriting codes and it didn't work.

```
$Variable1= $row['Variable1'];
$Variable2= $row['Variable2'];
$Variable3= $row['Variable3'];
$Variable4= $row['Variable4'];
$AllVariables= $row['AllVariables'];
```

And I'm putting inside of mysql  1,2,3 or 4, depends how many variables are set to 1. But I don't want to put manually the value (1,2,3 or 4) inside of mysql anymore, I want to auto deduct itself, or something like that, or even with mysql too, i don't know how to.

This is a notification system,  Variable1,2,3,4  are notifications and AllVariables is number of active notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you can just add all the variables.

```
$AllVariables = $Variable1 + $Variable2 + $Variable3 + $Variable4;

$sql = "UPDATE users
        SET AllVariables = $AllVariables
        WHERE id = '$username'";
```

Comment: So i should add $sql = UPDATE 'users' SET AllVariables = $Variable1 + $Variable2 + Variable3 + Variable4 WHERE id = $username;  ?

Comment: No, it should just be `Variable1`, not `$Variable1`. MySQL adds the columns in the database, you don't need to use PHP variables.

Comment: Tried to do with as you said, but it still shows 4 in MYSQL row and it echo 4 instead of two (2) because only 2 variables are set to 1  rest of it are 0. (No errors at E_ALL)

Comment: Can I modify the structrure of "AllVariables" row from MYSQL that his value to be Variable1+variable2+variable3+variable4  without updating it via PHP ?

Comment: I don't understand. if 2 are set to 1 and 2 are set to 0, then `1 + 1 + 0 + 0` is 2.

Comment: You need to check for errors explicitly: `$conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);`

Comment: Is `$username` a string? You need quotes around it. Even better would be to use a prepared statement.

Comment: yeah, but instead of 2 it shows me 4. i am using if(isset($_SESSION) and i am fetching rows (loopin throught table to get information) and later echoing them

Comment: The variables are the same as what's in the table, aren't they? So it should be the same to add them in PHP and add them in MySQL.

Comment: I guess I don't understand, I've changed the answer to add them in PHP.

Comment: Still no errors, but it doesn't update MYSQL value.  Here a picture

https://i.imgur.com/AVvdACJ.png

and picture of script https://i.imgur.com/Sul0vjB.png


I have to set "2" manually on Mysql

EDIT: This is the PHP part too. https://i.imgur.com/WWNHChZ.png 

On the script at WHERE id =  I modified it with WHERE username

Comment: Post your whole script in the question as plain text, not images.\

Comment: Done @Barmar. So, there is echo NotificariActive  which shows the currently active notifications (how many are set to 1.  And I put manually at Mysql  how many, it doesn't detect itself)